# How to close ZXing QrCode custom view

Tags: android, zxing

I use ZXing library to scan QrCode.
From the drawer menu i call a new intent where i start a custom activity scan with a custom view :

> integrator.setCaptureActivity(QrCodeCaptureActivity.class);

```
public class QrCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                private static final String TAG = "QrCodeActivity";
                private String message = "";

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrcode);

                    setToolbar();
                    scanBarcodeCustomLayout();

                }

                /** Set la toolbar */
                private void setToolbar(){
                  final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                }

                public void scanBarcodeCustomLayout() {
                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
                    integrator.setCaptureActivity(QrCodeCaptureActivity.class);
                    integrator.initiateScan();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    if(result != null) {
                        message = result.getContents();
                        if(result.getContents() == null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled scan");
                            finish();
                            // Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            showConfirmDialog();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Scanned: " + result.getContents());
                            // Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
                        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    }
                }

                private void showConfirmDialog(){
                    Intent confirmIntent = new Intent(QrCodeActivity.this, QrCodeConfirmActivity.class);
                    confirmIntent.putExtra(Constants.QR_CODE_MESSAGE, message);
                    startActivity(confirmIntent);
                }
}
```

The capture activity looks like this :

```
public class QrCodeCaptureActivity extends CaptureActivity {
    @Override
    protected DecoratedBarcodeView initializeContent() {
        setContentView(R.layout.capture_small);           
        return (DecoratedBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
    }
}
```

You can see, when the scan is done i open a new activity with the result for confirmation :

```
private void showConfirmDialog(){
                    Intent confirmIntent = new Intent(QrCodeActivity.this, QrCodeConfirmActivity.class);
                    confirmIntent.putExtra(Constants.QR_CODE_MESSAGE, message);
                    startActivity(confirmIntent);
                }
```

When i'm in this activity and when i close this, I return on a blank activity.
I think this blank activity is the Capture Activity for custom apparence :

> integrator.setCaptureActivity(QrCodeCaptureActivity.class);

Where is the mistake ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple thing you have to add in it ::
Add one new line after ::

```
startActivity(confirmIntent);
finish();
```

So your last QR code activity will be no longer visible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake ...
I call a activity instead of call directly the method

> integrator.initiateScan();